# adding indexes to a table through spring after on a already created table

Tags: database, spring, indexing

I read from another post on stackoverflow the following:

If you are using JPA 2.1 then you can use class annotation @Table with its attribute indexes

```
@Table(indexes = { @Index(name = "IDX_MYIDX1", columnList = "id,name,surname") })
```

Please note that as documentation says

> These are only used if table generation is in effect. Defaults to no
>   additional indexes.

I understand this approach doesn't modify indexes if the table is already generated. Is there any other way to add indexes using Spring ( and not directly accessing the database ) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute your own sql script on start up using.

```
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer

 <bean id="startupScripts" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer">
    <property name="dataSource"><ref bean="dataSource"/></property>
    <property name="databasePopulator"><ref bean="use ResourceDatabasePopulator"/></property>
</bean>
```